# Cannot embed textures in FBX file

Tags: openscenegraph

I need to rotate/resize an FBX with some embedded textures and I stumbled upon a weird problem.
Apparently, the file generated by OSGconv has external textures only, and there is no way to change this.
I'm using OSG 3.6.5 and this is the command line I am using.
I tried with OSG 3.6.4 as well.

```
osgconv.exe -e fbx -O Embedded --compressed -o 180-0,0,1 -s 100,100,100 input.fbx output.fbx

C:\Users\lcostant\Downloads\OpenSceneGraph-3.6.5-VC2017-64-Release\bin>osgconv.exe --format fbx Plugin osgPlugins-3.6.5/osgdb_fbx.dll

{
    ReaderWriter : FBX reader/writer
    {
        features   : readObject readNode writeNode
        extensions : .fbx                  FBX format
        options    : Embedded              (Write option) Embed textures in FBX file
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

All the plugin does is set the flag for Autodesk's FBX SDK to embed textures:

```
pSdkManager->GetIOSettings()->SetBoolProp(EXP_FBX_EMBEDDED, true);
```

The rest is a black box as far as OSG is concerned.

There are cases on autodesk forums where people have trouble getting textures to export for particular versions of the SDK, e.g.:
https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/fbx-forum/embedded-texture-not-working/td-p/7258470

In the thread above, there was an error in an older version of the FBX SDK where it got confused on mixed '\' and '/' - maybe updating your FBX or attempting to force a particular version's exporter with the plugin's FBX-ExportVersion option will help?